# How to use the DatasetAdapter's JSON export directly, without a RESTRequest?

Tags: json, delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

Delphi offers a [`DatasetAdapter`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Response.Adapter) to export and import datasets to standard JSONs in the form of arrays of objects, without all the quirkiness that `FDDataset.SaveToStream(Stream, sfJSON)` includes, resulting in shorter and much cleaner files.

This is my quick demo of that export and posterior import of Datasets to simple JSONs:

```
  // We clear prior JSON export files
  if TFile.Exists('export.json') then
    TFile.Delete('export.json');

  // We create a source Dataset
  var LSource := TFDMemTable.Create(Self);
  LSource.CachedUpdates := True;
  LSource.FieldDefs.Add('id', ftInteger);
  LSource.FieldDefs.Add('description', ftWideString, 100);

  // We populate the source Dataset
  LSource.CreateDataSet;
  LSource.Append;
  LSource.FieldValues['id'] := 1;
  LSource.FieldValues['description'] := 'apples';
  LSource.Post;
  LSource.Append;
  LSource.FieldValues['id'] := 2;
  LSource.FieldValues['description'] := 'oranges';
  LSource.Post;

  // We create the objects to export that Dataset to JSON
  var LRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(Self);
  var LRequestAdapter := TRESTRequestDataSetAdapter.Create(Self);
  LRequestAdapter.Request := LRequest;
  LRequestAdapter.AutoUpdate := false;
  LRequestAdapter.Dataset := LSource;

  // We export the source Dataset to JSON
  LRequestAdapter.UpdateParameter;
  TFile.WriteAllText('export.json', LRequest.GetFullRequestBody);

  // We create a target Dataset
  var LTarget := TFDMemTable.Create(Self);
  LTarget.CachedUpdates := True;
  LTarget.FetchOptions.Items := [];
  LTarget.FieldDefs.Add('id', ftInteger);
  LTarget.FieldDefs.Add('description', ftWideString, 100);

  // We create the objects to import our JSON data to the target Dataset
  var LResponseAdapter := TCustomJSONDatasetAdapter.Create(Self);
  LResponseAdapter.Dataset := LTarget;
  
  // We import the JSON data to the target Dataset
  LResponseAdapter.UpdateDataSet(TJSONValue.ParseJSONValue(TFile.ReadAllText('export.json')));

  // We check that the target contains the same data we populated into the source
  ShowMessage('RowCount: ' + LTarget.RecordCount.ToString + ', First Row: ' + LTarget.FieldByName('Description').AsString);
```

It works perfectly fine, but I wonder - can I avoid having to use an intermediate `TRESTRequest` during the export? Most of the time, I will want to put the resulting JSON into a RAD Server's `TEndpointResponse`, not into `TRESTRequest`.

The [`DatasetAdapter` unit](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Response.Adapter) provides the `TCustomJSONDatasetAdapter` class to import direct JSONs into Datasets without having to read them from `TRESTResponse`. But I can't find a similar class in that unit that allows to export Datasets directly to JSON (so I can place that JSON into an `EndpointResponse`, or further manipulate that JSON, like saving several of them into a single file to reduce round-trips to the backend, etc).  I don't like exporting that dataset inside the body of a `TRESTRequest` that I really won't use, slowing the process and adding unnecessary memory use.

Comment: Have you considered to use the underlying TDataSetToJSONBridge and TJSONToDataSetBridge directly?

Comment: @UweRaabe No, I didn't look at their internal composition. Those classes seem simple enough, Thank you, I will give them a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Uwe Raabe advice, I used the underlaying TDataSetToJSONBridge class (Data.DBJson unit) instead of the TRESTRequestDataSetAdapter, and now I can get the export JSON directly, without intermediate classes.

This is the updated demo:

```
  // We clear prior JSON export files
  if TFile.Exists('export.json') then
    TFile.Delete('export.json');

  // We create a source Dataset
  var LSource := TFDMemTable.Create(Self);
  LSource.CachedUpdates := True;
  LSource.FieldDefs.Add('id', ftInteger);
  LSource.FieldDefs.Add('description', ftWideString, 100);

  // We populate the source Dataset
  LSource.CreateDataSet;
  LSource.Append;
  LSource.FieldValues['id'] := 1;
  LSource.FieldValues['description'] := 'apples';
  LSource.Post;
  LSource.Append;
  LSource.FieldValues['id'] := 2;
  LSource.FieldValues['description'] := 'oranges';
  LSource.Post;

  // We export the source Dataset to JSON
  var ToJSONBridge := TDatasetToJSONBridge.Create;
  ToJSONBridge.Dataset := LSource;
  TFile.WriteAllText('export.json', ToJSONBridge.Produce.ToString);

  // We create a target Dataset
  var LTarget := TFDMemTable.Create(Self);
  LTarget.CachedUpdates := True;
  LTarget.FetchOptions.Items := [];
  LTarget.FieldDefs.Add('id', ftInteger);
  LTarget.FieldDefs.Add('description', ftWideString, 100);

  // We import the JSON data to the target Dataset
  var LResponseAdapter := TCustomJSONDatasetAdapter.Create(Self);
  LResponseAdapter.Dataset := LTarget;
  LResponseAdapter.UpdateDataSet(TJSONValue.ParseJSONValue(TFile.ReadAllText('export.json')));

  // We check that the target contains the same data we populated into the source
  ShowMessage('RowCount: ' + LTarget.RecordCount.ToString + ', First Row: ' + LTarget.FieldByName('Description').AsString);
```

Much simpler, and it seems to work fine. Thank you Uwe.